# Excel VBA Runtime error 1004 when saving file

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon, i'm trying to create an automatic backup when opening an Excel sheet, however occurs an error saying that wasn't possible find the file:

[link to image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTESp.png) 
(It's in Portuguese, but the message says: "Runtime error 1004: Could not find (sharepoint link.xlsm). Is it possible that it has been moved, renamed or deleted? ").

Follow the code:

```
Sub Autobackup()
'
' Autobackup Macro
'

'
    Dim path As String, name As String, data As String, ext As String
    path = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Gestao/Documentos Compartilhados/General/BACKUP Banco de Dados/"
    name = " Banco de Dados de Contratos"
    data = Format(Date, "ww.yyyy")
    ext = ".xlsm"

     ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:= _
        path & "Backup Semana " & data & name & ext

End Sub
```

The strange thing is that this error only occurs when I use the "SaveCopyAs" method. When I use the "SaveAs" method, Excel can find the path and save the file:

[link to image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZAXq.png)

But I don't want to save the sheet to another location, just make a copy of it.

Note that the code below is exactly the same as the one above, what only changes are the methods of the "ActiveWorkbook" object.

```
    Sub Autobackup()
    '
    ' Autobackup Macro
    '

    '
        Dim path As String, name As String, data As String, ext As String
        path = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/Gestao/Documentos Compartilhados/General/BACKUP Banco de Dados/"
        name = " Banco de Dados de Contratos"
        data = Format(Date, "ww.yyyy")
        ext = ".xlsm"

         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            path & "Backup Semana " & data & name & ext

End Sub
```

That is, the path is right, but for some reason, Excel cannot save a copy. Does anyone know explain to me why?

Comment: `SaveCopyAs` must be saved with the same file extension. Do you change the extension when saving?

Comment: No, I did not change the extension, it's the same ".xlsm" for both. As a said, the only thing that I changed in the code was the methods.